# Stellar Ledger / Hash uniqueness

Tags: stellar-core, operations, horizon

I've seen many transactions with the same hash. However, is it safe to say that ledger/hash pairs are unique and there are no scenarios where two transactions on the same ledger share a hash?

Comment: It would be great to see some examples from the horizon api.

Comment: You're probably talking about operations. https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/219/does-the-ratio-of-number-of-transaction-of-number-of-operation-mean-something?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
I've seen many transactions with the same hash.
```

If transaction has the same hash as the other one it means they are identical.

You can have two transactions that are doing the same thing (ex. sending 1 XLM from A to B) but they need to have a different sequence numbers and this will make their hashes different.